# Extract plot from val.prob() function from rms package

Tags: r

The `val.prob()` function from the `rms` package in R creates as an output a figure that examines the calibration of a fitted model in external data. According to the documentation, you should be able to obtain the plot from the output of the `val.prob()` function. However, the plot is not saved. I have gone through the [source code](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/val.prob.s) and I can't figure out how I would obtain the plot for further manipulation and saving in the correct format.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 200
x1 <- runif(n)
x2 <- runif(n)
x3 <- runif(n)
logit <- 2*(x1-.5)
P <- 1/(1+exp(-logit))
y <- ifelse(runif(n)<=P, 1, 0)
d <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
f <- lrm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, subset=1:100)
pred.logit <- predict(f, d[101:200,])
phat <- 1/(1+exp(-pred.logit))
val.prob(phat, y[101:200], m=20, cex=.5)  # subgroups of 20 obs.
```

The output of the above code is the following figure.

[image: Calibration plot]

However if I perform the exact code above, but save the output `v <- val.prob(phat, y[101:200], m=20, cex=.5)` and then do `plot(v)` I get the following figure

[image: gibberish]

Comment: After running the code in the question run `v <- recordPlot()` .  Then `replayPlot(v)` will plot it again.  This works at least on Windows.